# Looking for a book on set theory that covers cardinals, proper classes, extensions of ZFC etc. in detail

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, book-recommendation

I'm fine with "naive" set theory and low level mathematical logic, however I want to understand set theory in particular at a deeper and more formal level. I want to learn more about cardinals as well as other higher order sets and about proper classes and formally handling them. It would be nice if the book had a formal definition of ZFC and also talked about maybe a few other popular extensions of ZFC like NGB or something. I know anything like this is going to require some more advanced mathematical logic that I may not have, so its fine if it has to go over that in some detail. However I want to try and maximize the ratio of set theory to mathematical logic as much as possible. Now I'm not sure where to start looking so if anyone experienced in these subjects could recommend a book to me, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila If you have any advice please, I'd appreciate anything.

Comment: Jech.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://logic.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Jech%2C+T.+J.+%282003%29.+Set+Theory+%28The+3rd+millennium+ed.%29.pdf? It looks very good though I want to be sure I'm getting the book you are referring to.

Comment: Yeah, that one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, if you post the word Jech as an answer I'll accept it =)

Comment: Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs by K. Kunen..... I have the first edition. I think there may be a new, revised edition.

Comment: As a self learner of logic I find it easier at times to have several books to refer to instead of just one, especially when presentation of some particular materials of an author is hard to grasp. Peter Smith has a list of books on practically all fields of logic with varying difficulty/coverage: http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2017.pdf

Comment: @DanielMak I don't have much money and the books are quite expensive, do you have any recommendations? Outside of paying hundreds. I like to have non electronic copies because I only get internet access a day or two of the week.

Comment: There are ways to download PDFs of some of these books from the internet, but you need to know where to look. You can try Googling for them. Alternatively, I am not sure what the situation is at your country, but in where I live some of these books are available in the public library.